# Create a solution to automatically split addresses into their separate components using python

Tags: machine-learning, automation, classification

I am trying to find a solution for being able to automatically split address into their separate components using python.
below is some sample data

| Full Address | Street Number | Street | City | State | Zip Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 661 Camel Back Road Tulsa Oklahoma 74120 | 661 | Camel Back Road | Tulsa |  | Oklahoma |
| 68 Gnatty Creek Road Roslyn New York 11576 | 68 | Gnatty Creek Road | Roslyn |  | New York |
| 1 Raccoon Run Seattle Washington 98119 | 1 | Raccoon Run |  | Seattle | Washington |
| 616 Friendship Lane Santa Clara California 95054 | 616 | Friendship Lane | Santa Clara | California | 95054 |
| 3878 Grand Avenue Maitland Florida 32751 | 3878 | Grand Avenue | Maitland | Florida | 32751 |

The above data is a representation of what I am trying to achieve.
on the left is my input address, and on the right is the result after having being split out automatically.
The problem here, as cannot be seen in this over simplified example, is that the input addresses don't come in the same order, and will include components such as names of buildings etc.

My options so far are the following:

1. REGEX
2. MACHINE LEARNING MODEL

The REGEX option is familiar, but it will still be largely inaccurate. I need this solution to be as accurate as possible.

The MACHINE LEARNING MODEL option is more difficult in that I am not aware of any model or framework capable of classifying multiple categories as once.
Can anyone help?

so far I haven't really started the REGEX in anticipation of major gaps in capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this and get a fairly accurate result is to get the list of zip codes, for instance from here:
https://www.zipcode.com.ng/2022/06/list-of-5-digit-zip-codes-united-states.html?m=1
and a list of US cities.

Then you can match the zip code, state and city to the lists.